# how to apply nginx rewrite from htaccess

Tags: nginx

I installed ispconfig/nginx on ubuntu 12.10 following "perfect server" here:
http://www.howtoforge.com/forums/showthread.php?t=61141

I need to apply rewrite rules to nginx from a .haccess file with these contents:

RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*)-video_(.*).html$ musicvideo.php?vid=$3

RewriteRule ^([^/]*)-video_(.*).html$ watch.php?vid=$2

i used an online converter and got this output:

```
location / {
rewrite ^/(.*)/(.*)-video_(.*).html$ /musicvideo.php?vid=$3;

rewrite ^/([^/]*)-video_(.*).html$ /watch.php?vid=$2;
}
```

Then I put the code in `./sites-available/default` under server block and restarted nginx but I am getting error:

```
duplicate location "/" in /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default:133
nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test failed
```

and If I put my rewrite rules within the existing Location:

```
location / {
            # First attempt to serve request as file, then
            # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
            try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
            # Uncomment to enable naxsi on this location
            # include /etc/nginx/naxsi.rules
rewrite ^/(.*)/(.*)-video_(.*).html$ /musicvideo.php?vid=$3;

rewrite ^/([^/]*)-video_(.*).html$ /watch.php?vid=$2;
}
```

then nothing happens! could someone please point out to me what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

The order of directives matters in nginx.  Try moving the rewrite rules up to the top of the `/` `location`.